# HashMap with a Pair has a strange value in the database

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

When I insert a object into my db with a rest controller I get for the Value of the Map, which is a Pair, a really strange string in the db, is this serialized? Can someone explain?

```
"openHours": {
    "monday": {
        "first": "19:58",
        "second": "20:58"
    }
}
```

Part of the model:

```
    @ElementCollection
    var openHours: Map<String, Pair<LocalTime, LocalTime >> = HashMap()
```

Database:

> key: monday

> value:
> aced00057372000b6b6f746c696e2e50616972fa1b06813de78f780200024c000566697273747400124c6a6176612f6c616e672f4f626a6563743b4c00067365636f6e6471007e000178707372000d6a6176612e74696d652e536572955d84ba1b2248b20c0000787077030413c5787371007e000377030414c578

Comment: If you're storing a ``Pair<LocalTime, LocalTime>`` in a single field it will need to be serialized into a format the database can store. It looks some binary data, but I'm not familiar with spring so I don't know what format it would use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is java ObjectSerialization format.

You can use `ObjectInputStream` to de-serialize the object.

Like so :

```java
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream( .. you data here ... ));

Pair<LocalTime, LocalTime > pair = (Pair<LocalTime, LocalTime >) ois.readObject();
```